# Why doesn't the Protagonist use one of Ives' inverters to heal Kat?

Tags: tenet

After Kat is injured, Ives says something to the effect of "where are you going to be able to find an inverter that existed 2 weeks ago?" But later, it is revealed that Ives' team has access to a large suite of inverters (which they use for the final operation). **Why couldn't Ives just direct the Protagonist to one of those?**

Comment: 'Knowledge divided' and 'lying is standard operating procedure' are a common theme in explaining these scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, the problem is the Protagonist couldn't know that the inverters existed yet. That would create a paradox where the Protagonist would potentially look for a way to use the inverters ahead of the final operation. Those inverters were also secret, as they were a key part of the final operation, which was the last chance at stopping the algorithm.

Comment: At that point in the movie, the Protagonist was just told what inverters are and how they work. So what is the issue with using one that Ives' team controls?

Comment: The Protagonist knows about inverters, but he doesn't know about Ives's inverters. And those in particular are a secret weapon. It doesn't seem that Sator knew about those, or he would likely have made an attempt at sabotaging the final operation.